# Under what conditions can we assume action-reaction force pairs are along the line joining two objects (strong form of Newton's third law)?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, angular-momentum, free-body-diagram

In many circumstances we take it that when object $A$ applies a force on object $B$ and vice-versa, the two forces are *central forces* or *along the line joining $A$ and $B$.* This is used to derive conservation of angular momentum from Newton's laws.

However, people have also said that this isn't always true. In [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/760588/), a comment said,

> The "strong form" of Newton's third law does not always hold. The force between magnetic dipoles, for example, is not central, nor are chemical forces. Angular momentum conservation cannot be derived from the third laws because it depends on a different symmetry: momentum conservation comes from a translation symmetry and angular momentum conservation from rotational symmetry. Elementry books usually cheat on this

Even Frank Wilczek himself [notes this here](https://pubs.aip.org/physicstoday/article/57/10/11/412402/Whence-the-Force-of-F-ma-I-Culture-Shock):

> When most textbooks come to discuss angular momentum, they introduce a fourth law, that forces between bodies are directed along the line that connects them. It is introduced in order to “prove” the conservation of angular momentum. But this fourth law isn’t true at all for molecular forces.

So this brings up the following questions:

- What exactly are the circumstances where we can assume the strong form of Newton's third law? What are the circumstances where we can't? Are there any specific forces that can be named?
- If it doesn't hold for molecular forces, then why do we assume it holds for macroscopic objects?
- If it doesn't always hold, does that mean that conservation of angular momentum doesn't hold? What are the circumstances where it isn't conserved?

Comment: Possible duplicates: [Is there any case in classical mechanics where Newton's (strong) third law doesn't hold?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/51757/2451) and links therein.

Comment: This is more matter if science history... but while Newton seems to have understood the notion of angular momentum conservation (he talks about spinning tops being slowed down by friction only, I believe), it's not clear that he intended to bake it into what are today known as the three laws. Based on the usual derivation of the requirements for angular momentum conservation it seems to me more likely that it's not really in there. I wouldn't go at it from Newton's laws, anyway. I would focus on Noether's theorem. It's far more universal.